# ASP.NET MVC - Custom data type using enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I would like to create a custom data type from a property on one of my classes. I know that this is possible but unfortunately, I lack the knowledge to know what is wrong with my code.

I'm getting the following error message:

```
"Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
The relationship 'GarethLewisWeb.Models.Photo_Set' was not loaded because the type
'GarethLewisWeb.Models.Photo' is not available.
The following information may be useful in resolving the previous error:
The property 'Orientation' on the type 'GarethLewisWeb.Models.Photo' has a property 
type of 'GarethLewisWeb.Models.Photo+Orientations' which cannot be mapped to a
PrimitiveType."
```

Here is the code for my Photo.cs class which I think is causing the problem.

```
public class Photo
{
    public int PhotoID { get; set; }
    public int PhotoOrder { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string FileLocation { get; set; }
    public Orientations Orientation { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public bool FeaturedPhoto { get; set; }

    public enum Orientations
    {
        Square = 0,
        Landscape = 1,
        Portrait = 2
    }

    public virtual Set Set { get; set; }
    public virtual PhotoExif PhotoExif { get; set; }
}
```

Any help appeciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CustomModelBinder, it should solve your problem, here is a good article about it

http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/03/18/a-better-model-binder/